# how can I limit my list items within div element only?

Tags: html, css

I want to limit the size of my list item in the `front` class, so that my list appears within the card boundaries. But now only the first item in the list shows within the card and the rest of the items appears outside of the card.
This is the original code: [click here to see the code in code pen](https://codepen.io/ianseabrook/pen/jIrGk?fbclid=IwAR2ClVRaDqVaLNT6H1DU4gwCE7aWveTb24LQ2y87RBSVeQy2boNuFqm3yDM)

Here is my html code:

```
<div class="flip-container" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
    <div class="flipper">
        <div class="front">
            <!-- front content -->
            <div class="p">
                <ul>
                    <li>Coffee</li>
                    <li>Tea</li>
                    <li>Milk</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="back">
            <!-- back content -->
            <img src="https://miro.medium.com/max/1620/1*MKkufG0eyT0IQ5wZ70qKxQ.jpeg" alt="Girl in a jacket"  width=100% height=100%
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

here is my CSS code:

```
/* entire container, keeps perspective */
.flip-container {
    perspective: 1000;
}
    /* flip the pane when hovered */
    .flip-container:hover .flipper, .flip-container.hover .flipper {
        transform: rotateY(180deg);
    }

.flip-container, .front, .back {
    width: 320px;
    height: 240px;
  margin: 1em auto;
}

/* flip speed goes here */
.flipper {
    transition: 0.6s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;

    position: relative;
}

/* hide back of pane during swap */
.front, .back {
    backface-visibility: hidden;

    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
   color: cornSilk;
   text-align: center;
   font: 3em/240px 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;
   box-shadow: -5px 5px 5px #aaa;
}

/* front pane, placed above back */
.front {
    z-index: 2;
    /* for firefox 31 */
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  background: cornflowerBlue;
}

/* back, initially hidden pane */
.back {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
  background: crimson;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove some padding from the `ul` and decrease the line-height, so more items will fit. Add this:

```
.front ul{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
.front ul li{
    line-height:1.5;
}
```